# Searching for a precise term for a SQL phrase

Tags: sql

I'm trying to document some SQL and wanted to get the right terminology. If you write SQL like so;

```
select child.ID, parent.ID
from hierarchy child 
inner join hierarchy parent 
on child.parentId = parent.ID
```

Then you have one actual table ('hierarchy') which you are giving two names ('parent' and 'child') My question is about how you refer to the logical entity of a table with a name.

What would you write in the blank here for the name?

"This query uses one table (hierarchy) but two **_** (child and parent)"

[edit] left a previous draft in the question. now corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SQL Server docs, the term is `table_source` :

> Specifies a table, view, or derived table source, with or without an alias, to use in the Transact-SQL statement

In the BNF grammar, it's:

```
<table_source> ::= 
{
        table_or_view_name [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ <tablesample_clause> ] 
        [ WITH ( < table_hint > [ [ , ]...n ] ) ] 
    | rowset_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ] 
        [ ( bulk_column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ] 
        | user_defined_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ (column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]
    | OPENXML <openxml_clause> 
    | derived_table [ AS ] table_alias [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ] 
    | <joined_table> 
    | <pivoted_table> 
    | <unpivoted_table>
      | @variable [ [ AS ] table_alias ]
        | @variable.function_call ( expression [ ,...n ] ) [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ (column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is called a SELF JOIN.  A and B (or "child" and "parent", I think you have a typo in your question) are called ALIASes or TABLE ALIASes.

Answer (score 4):

The concept is a `self join`.  However, the `a` is a syntax error.  The table is `hierarchy`, the alias is `child`.

I would call each part of a self join an `instance`.

Comment: "I would call each part of a self join an `instance`" I'd call each a `table` i.e. base `table`, viewed `table`, derived `table`, common `table` expression, etc.

Comment: @onedaywhen I agree in most cases, except when specifically when doing a self-join I use instance.  i.e. Join from the parent instance of the hierarchy table to the child instance of the hierarchy table.

Comment: For me this implies that the table is being instantiated when it is not. No biggie, though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
'child', 'parent'
```

The term used in the SQL-92 Standard spec is "correlation name", being a type of "identifier".

```
'hierarchy'
```

The term used in the SQL-92 Standard spec is "table".

Hence the answer to your (edited) question is:

> This query uses one table (hierarchy)
>   but two correlation names (child and
>   parent).